# Convert excel Color BGR to RGB

Tags: c#, excel

I found an [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01735cbf-b11b-4dc5-857a-3d27613149d4/c-and-excel-incorrect-color-conversion) saying the value returned by `Interior.Color` is in BGR and I'm trying to convert it to RGB but I still got weird color

And I'm trying to retrieve a base color in an excel cell to light it using`ControlPaint.Light` like this :

```
int rgbColor = ExcelDoc.BGRToRGB((int)contentCanonical.Interior.Color);

Color canonicalColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(rgbColor);
Color backgroundColor = ControlPaint.Light(canonicalColor, 75);
```

here is my convert method

```
public static int BGRToRGB(int bgr)
{
    byte[] hexBGR;
    byte[] hexRGB = new byte[4] {0,0,0,0};

    hexBGR = BitConverter.GetBytes(bgr);

    hexRGB[0] = hexBGR[0];
    hexRGB[1] = hexBGR[3];
    hexRGB[2] = hexBGR[2];
    hexRGB[3] = hexBGR[1];

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(hexRGB, 0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the color is the color you think it is at both stages? (put the bytes into a web app that displays the color or use mspaint)

Comment: Yes using the VS debugger I can see that the `contentCanonical.Interior.Color` is the good one but then when it convert it, the color completely change

Comment: the math formula is BGR = (blue * 65536) + (green * 256) + red if that helps

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Well it looks light it's the `ControlPaint.Light` that is doing something weird, it Lights `0,159,227` to `155,47,255` which is completely different

Comment: I know nothing about Excel but the last time I saw RGB reversed it was not alone: A ways also on 4th. So it was BGRA as opposed to ARGB. (It was the actual byte order in the Lockbit buffer)

Comment: I found the problem the percent used in Light is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this [method](http://www.davetyner.com/forum/forum/intergraph-smartplant/integraph-smartplant-review/13008-net-system-drawing-color-to-0brg-integer-format) returns the color

```
public static Color From0BGR(int bgrColor)
{
    // Get the color bytes
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bgrColor);

    // Return the color from the byte array
    return Color.FromArgb(bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2]);
}
```

this returns the bgr color int from an rgb color

```
public static int Get0BGR(Color rgbColor)
{
    // Return a zero-alpha 24-bit BGR color integer
    return (0 << 24) + (rgbColor.B << 16) + (rgbColor.G << 8) + rgbColor.R;
}
```

Comment: thanks I used it to directly put the returned color into the Light method it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this functions (I'm "cutting" the alfa parts of the color)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the color to an Argb color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">Color to convert</param>
    /// <returns>The Argb color</returns>
    public static int ToArgb(int color)
    {
        int Argb = (color >> 16) | (color & 0xFF) << 16 | (color & 0x00FF00);
        return Argb;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the color to a MSO Color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Argb">Color to convert</param>
    /// <returns>The MSO color</returns>
    public static int ToMsoColor(int Argb)
    {
        Argb &= 0xFFFFFF;
        int color = (Argb >> 16) | (Argb & 0xFF) << 16 | (Argb & 0x00FF00);
        return color;
    }
```